# Laravel scope function Eloquent returns STD object

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a Laravel Eloquent `scopeFunction` but it returns std object even though I use

`toArray()` method.

It is a conditional `scopeFunction`, the first condition returns `std::` object while the second

one works well and returns array. Can anyone see what is the problem?

```
function scopeGetList($query, $firstId, $limit, $catid = 'all')
    {
        $cats = NULL;
        if($catid != NULL && $catid != 'all')
        {
            $cats = CategoryList::where("cat_id", "=", $catid)->get()->toArray();
            $res = NULL;
            foreach($cats as $cat)
            {
                $res[] = $query->where("id", "=", $cat['item_id'])->take($limit)->skip($firstId)->orderby("id")->get()->toArray();
            }
            return $res;
        }
        else
        {
            return $query->take($limit)->skip($firstId)->orderby("id")->get()->toArray();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does allow you to change how databases results are returned, i.e. their format.

From api/config/database.php:

```
"By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style."
```

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters):

```
fetch_style
Controls how the next row will be returned to the caller. This value must be 
one of PDO::FETCH_* constants, defaulting to value of PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE 
(which defaults to PDO::FETCH_BOTH).
```

In your case, please see:

```
PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set
```

Hope that helps!